# auth-user-pass-verify openvpn error

Tags: windows, openvpn

I tried to add the custom script to auth-user-pass-verify through server conf but when I tried to start the openvpn getting error as

auth-user-pass-verify "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\author.bat" via-file

script-security 3

Options error: the --auth-user-pass-verify directive should have at most 2 parameters. To pass a list of arguments as one of the parameters, try enclosing them in double quotes ("").
Use --help for more information.

Any suggestions ?

using openvpn 2.5.7

Comment: you need either double quote both or all in one. The error is very clear in its statement: it miss a operator

Comment: auth-user-pass-verify "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\author.bat" "via-file"


auth-user-pass-verify "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\author.bat via-file"

Did you mean either of above one?/ If so I tried both one and getting same error.

Comment: and both without a double quote?

Comment: both without double quote return same error.